# pass file through angular service to nodejs api

Tags: angularjs, node.js

**controller:**

```
User.uploadimg(theFile, function(response){
      console.log('upload response---------------------->'+response);

    })
```

**service:**

```
  userFactory.uploadimg = function(info, callback){
    $http({
        url:'api/testupload',
        method:'POST',
        headers:{'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        data:{'fileData':info}
    })
        .success(function(response){
            callback(response);
        })
}
```

**api:**

```
 api.post('/testupload', function(req , res) {
    var file = req.body.fileData;
 }
```

i am calling a service from controller.... the file is being passed to the service... now how to pass it to the api and access it in the api??? Please help.!! I'm new to this.

Comment: I need only the path of the file in the api... but as i've read i cannot directly access and send path of file through the service... so how to do this?

Comment: Would be better if you can post complete code, how you are calling your service, how is your controller/service.. everything related to this.

Comment: can you come on chat or teamviewer please? @developer033

Comment: i dont have access to send messages in chat @developer033

Comment: @kRAk3N : have u found solution for this now ..?If yes then tell me whats problem in this bcuz im at this situation.